# How Can I Save a List of objects in setting file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I Want to save a list of objects in 'setting file' in C# Winform. I can use List Dictionary but its a pair (key,value) list. How can I save a list or collection (IEnumberable) in Resource file?

[image]

Comment: What about comma separated (,) list of words, that you split to get an array?

Comment: What kind of resource file are you talking about? There are several possibilities with .Net programs, for example the resx files associated with WinForms and the Visual Studio designer, and there are embedded resource files, and several other kinds.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot No my object has many properties and I can't split it by comma!

Comment: @RenniePet I'm talking about setting files.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just `Browse...` to find the collection type you're looking for?

Comment: OK, I'm not an expert on this, but I think you're actually confusing the issue by repeatedly calling this a "resource file" - I don't think that's a usual way to talk about settings files. You could also drop the "Winforms" and "Visual Studio" tags, your problem is not really related to them, and instead add a "settings file" tag. Anyway, if you're talking about .Net application settings, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx And search for information about .Net application settings. My understanding is you can serialize anything into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can do a search for additional collections, you are not limited to what is shown the only limitations that I know of is the use of a generic collection.  You can always use an `ArrayList` or there is a `StringCollection` available. You can get to them by clicking the browse then navigating to `mscorlib --> System.Collections --> ArrayList` or  `System --> System.Collections.Specialized --> StringCollection`.  But since you are needing an object I would probably use the [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) since it appears that Generics are not an option in this situation.

[image]